# OpenLayers - Using google maps

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I'm creating a web application using Google Maps and OpenLayers, about comercial terms of Google Map, could I show positons of cellphone in real time? Is it against the terms?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding Yes. A simple search should show you the license terms http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html.

If I were you, I will probably use OpenLayers with openstreetmap data.